# Include attribute from joined class into autogenerated JPA select

Tags: sql, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Using the following example classes, when I try to list the leaves ordered by the employee's lastName attribute, I get the following error message:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: for SELECT DISTINCT, ORDER BY expressions must appear in select list

Class for storing employee leaves:

```
@Entity(name = "Leave")
data class LeaveEntity(
  @NotNull
  @ManyToOne()
  @JoinColumn(name = "employeeId")
  var employee: EmployeeEntity,
  ... 
)
```

The class for storing the employees:

```
@Entity(name = "Employee")
class EmployeeEntity(
  @NotNull
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
  var id: UUID? = null,
  @NotNull
  var firstName: String,
  @NotNull
  var lastName: String,
  ...
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "employee", targetEntity = LeaveEntity::class)
  var leave: MutableList<LeaveEntity> = mutableListOf(),
)
```

In my head, they should be connected, so the ordering would be possible, but it seems that is not the case.

I also enabled jpa to show sql queries that it generates, they look like this:

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        distinct leaveentit0_.id as id1_5_,
        leaveentit0_.crdat as crdat2_5_,
        leaveentit0_.crby as crby3_5_,
        leaveentit0_.mddat as mddat4_5_,
        leaveentit0_.mdby as mdby5_5_,
        leaveentit0_.tenant_id as tenant_i6_5_,
        leaveentit0_.comment as comment7_5_,
        leaveentit0_.employee_id as employe12_5_,
        leaveentit0_.status as status8_5_,
        leaveentit0_.time_end as time_end9_5_,
        leaveentit0_.time_start as time_st10_5_,
        leaveentit0_.type as type11_5_ 
    from
        leave leaveentit0_ 
    left outer join
        employee employeeen1_ 
            on leaveentit0_.employee_id=employeeen1_.id 
    where
        leaveentit0_.tenant_id=? 
    order by
        employeeen1_.last_name asc limit ?
```

I'm thinking I should somehow add the employeeName explicitly to the select, but have not managed to find a way to do that. Would that be the correct solution or the problem comes from the way these two classes are connected, and just changing that would solve the problem?

Comment: Please add an appropiate tag for your used rmdbs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my case, the solution was using the @Formula annotation. The problem was that the query did not include every necessary field by default, as they would have been filled in after the database call ended. But since I asked for the data to be ordered by one of the connected entity's field, and the whole connected entity did not load in, it couldn't ask for the name field, and that's why the problem arose.

To connect the elements, I had to apply the @Formula annotation. May be easier explained with an example for the above situation. In the annotation, you have to write a simple sql, connecting the two tables together on some field. In the case of the employee.lastName it would look something like this:

```
@Entity(name = "Leave")
data class LeaveEntity(

  @NotNull
  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "employeeId")
  var employee: EmployeeEntity,
  ...
) : TenantOwnedBaseEntity() {

  @Formula("(select employee.last_name from employee where employee.id = employee_id)")
  var employeeLastName: String = ""
}
```

This way, when the DB query is called, we will have the employeeLastName field filled out, getting something like a "virtual column". We don't store it in the DB, but we will have it when we call a query, and be able to order the results by this value.
Note that this way, instead of calling employee.lastName as the field for the filtering, you will have to use employeeLastName, since that's the field where the value is stored.

Now this solution is supposedly only works if all included classes are in the same database, but in my problem, that was the case.

Another solution, albeit not pretty, would have been to separately include the employeeLastName attribute in the LeaveEntity class. It would result in redundant data storage, but in the case when the entities are in different databases, it would solve the problem with ordering by the field. The value would also have to be maintained, since changing the connected EmployeeEntity would not automatically change the value stored in employeeLastName, it would be required to be done by hand.